# ServiceNow Community GeoJSON file - ref_frame and label_area understanding

Tags: geojson, here-api, servicenow

I'm looking to create GeoJSON files to upload as part of the Space Management application in ServiceNow to create Campus floor-plans.

Looking through the documentation for ServiceNow's Space Management and HERE Venues GeoJSON spec sheet (https://venues.here.com/documentation/geojson-spec), I'm still uncertain how to build a few elements in the "Community File" which is uploaded first when doing a campus floor-plan buildout.

The areas that I don't understand are the ref_frame objects and the label_area objects that are defined in example GeoJSON files.

HERE venues describes the ref_frame below, however I'm not sure where I'm supposed to get these values from. When using geojson.io to build out my map files, I don't create anything similar to this.

```
 "ref_frame":{
             "transform": transform from local to lat lon coordinates
             "height": height in local coordinates
             "width": width in local coordinates
             "angle_deg": default angle,
             "local2m": scale factor to convert local coords to meters
             }   




{"id":78,"languages":["en"],"drawings":[{"id":78,

"ref_frame":{"transform":[6.467651296807697E-8,-6.07648087125996E-6,-7.870197492026888E-6,-5.296876558604206E-8,-121.940930,37.326973],"height":1135.860,"angle_deg":89.501,"width":505.230,"local2m":0.686517220008541},

"levels":[{"id":232,"properties":{"name":"1","zlevel":0,"main":true},"obj_type":"Level"},{"id":233,"properties":{"name":"2","zlevel":1},"obj_type":"Level"},{"id":37405,"properties":{"name":"3","zlevel":2},"obj_type":"Level"}],"properties":{"is_root":true,"display_name":"Westfield Valley Fair","map_type":"Shopping Mall","name":"Westfield Valley Fair"},"obj_type":"Drawing"}],"location":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-121.9457010,37.3253650]},"entity_version":278,"default_lang":"en","properties":{"phone":"(408) 248.4451","street address":"2855 Stevens Creek Blvd","hours":"Mon-Sat 10:30am - 9:00pm, Sun  11:00am - 6:00pm","description":"Westfield Valley Fair Shopping Mall","name":"Westfield Valley Fair","state":"CA","com_type":"Shopping Mall","default_lang":"en","url":"http://westfield.com/valleyfair/","city":"Santa Clara","country":"US","postal code":"95050"},"map_version":278,"obj_type":"CommunityMap"}
```

Answer (score 0):

This information is generated by the HERE internal tool when they create the indoor venue. ref_frame is like a canvas and provide information about the conversion of the local coordinates to lat-lon, height, width, angle from north and scale factor. While, label_area is a rectangular area created for a geometry to render the label in given space. The value is given as a json array: [center X, center Y, width, height, angle]. Center X and Y are mostly centroid of the geometry, height and width values are calculated based on the geometry shape and angle is for rotation of the label on the map.